# Select an item in Select tag in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I don't understand why my value isn't selected.

I have an editItem(the object type is Entity) with a field containing the name of another item (Object type Sponsor).

In the example below, Sponsor_name is the name of a Sponsor Object

Here is my model (The "entity" object)

```
{
  "id": 130,
  "Entity_name": "RH-commun",
  "Entity_sponsor": "AUFC",
  "Entity_billing_code": "137"
}
```

Here is the list of sponsors(subObjectList)

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "objectType": "Sponsor",
  "content": "{\"id\": 376316, \"Sponsor_name\": \"AUFC\"}",
  "previewContent": {
    "id": 1,
    "Sponsor_name": "AUFC"
  },
 "relationNumber": null
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "objectType": "Sponsor",
  "content": "{\"id\": 376317, \"Sponsor_name\": \"B3G\"}",
  "previewContent": {
  "id": 2,
  "Sponsor_name": "B3G"
  },
 "relationNumber": null
 }
]
```

Now this is my Html in my Angular code

```
$scope.form += '<select class="form-control"  id="' + keyname + '" name="' + keyname + '" type="text"  ng-model="editItem.previewContent.' + keyname + '"  ng-options="item.previewContent.' + childName + ' for item in subObjectList track by item.previewContent.' + childName + '"  ng-required="' + isRequired + '"  /> '
```

`keyname` is equal to `"Entity_sponsor"` and `childname` is equal to `"Sponsor_name"`

This is the final generated html for the select :

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" id="Entity_sponsor" name="Entity_sponsor" type="text" ng-model="editItem.previewContent.Entity_sponsor" ng-options="item.previewContent.Sponsor_name for item in subObjectList track by item.previewContent.Sponsor_name" ng-required="true" required="required">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option><option label="AUFC" value="AUFC">AUFC</option>
    <option label="B3G" value="B3G">B3G</option><option label="B-DIG" value="B-DIG">B-DIG</option>
    <option label="BEEI" value="BEEI">BEEI</option><option label="BEF" value="BEF">BEF</option>
    <option label="BIN" value="BIN">BIN</option><option label="DEC" value="DEC">DEC</option><option label="DGAZ" value="DGAZ">DGAZ</option><option label="DGF" value="DGF">DGF</option>
    <option label="DGR" value="DGR">DGR</option><option label="DOAAT" value="DOAAT">DOAAT</option><option label="DPNT" value="DPNT">DPNT</option><option label="DSP" value="DSP">DSP</option>
    <option label="ERD" value="ERD">ERD</option><option label="ENEDIS" value="ENEDIS">ENEDIS</option>
    <option label="FCC" value="FCC">FCC</option><option label="FIL" value="FIL">FIL</option>
    <option label="GRDF" value="GRDF">GRDF</option><option label="PREST" value="PREST">PREST</option>
    <option label="RTE" value="RTE">RTE</option><option label="SEI" value="SEI">SEI</option>
    <option label="SG" value="SG">SG</option><option label="TIE" value="TIE">TIE</option>
    <option label="DPIH" value="DPIH">DPIH</option><option label="DIPNN" value="DIPNN">DIPNN</option>
    <option label="DISP" value="DISP">DISP</option><option label="DI" value="DI">DI</option>
</select>
```

So for each Entity items, if I'm editing one, the select for the sponsor binded to  the Entity object is empty. This list is filled by sponsors items, but no way to have a selected value

Comment: Please replace images with JSON data.

Comment: why are you having `$scope.form` html in controller; can you directly put that HTML code in View ?

Comment: no because I'm generating dynamic forms, with different kind of objects. But it works with other components like <input type="text" />. I get values of my editItem but not with the select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found :

replace

```
ng-options="item.previewContent.' + childName + ' for item in subObjectList track by item.previewContent.' + childName + '"  ng-required="' + isRequired + '"  /> '
```

by

```
ng-options="item.previewContent.' + childName + ' as item.previewContent.' + childName + ' for item in subObjectList '
```